# What does T.A.H.I.T.I stand for?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, agents-of-shield

Everyone following Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D would have heard of the **T.A.H.I.T.I** Project. Any clue what it stands for?

Comment: It's a magical place...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The Agents of SHIELD [Wiki page on the project](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Project_T.A.H.I.T.I.) describes it as thusly;

> *Project T.A.H.I.T.I. (**Terrestrialized Alien Host Integrative Tissue I.**) was a S.H.I.E.L.D. Level 9 project ordered by Director Nick Fury
>   and overseen by Agent Phil Coulson. It involved the harvesting of an
>   alien corpse for medicinal purposes. It was only to be used if an
>   Avenger had died. Since Nick Fury considered Agent Coulson just as
>   important, he put the project in action when Coulson was killed by
>   Loki after the Attack on the Helicarrier.*

The final word isn't shown. There's some speculation that it's "initiative"

[image]

Comment: @JashJacob - Personally, I wouldn't accept this yet given that it's an incomplete answer. Someone else might know what the missing letter is.

Comment: Re: "and overseen by Agent Phil Coulson": That's odd. How come he seems to know so little about it, then?

Comment: @ruakh - Dunno. I've not been watching.

Comment: @ruakh He was caused to forget by the events of the show's backstory. This is revealed toward the end of Season 1 and is a major plot point, so I'll refrain from going into detail.

Comment: @ruakh Coulson's involvement with the project is shown in Season 2.

Comment: The reason why Coulson forgot about the project that he was the head of is that during the process of the TAHITI project, the majority of test subjects needed to have their memories wiped. This included Coulson.

Comment: It's a magical place...